# flink "equal" symbol changed inside a string

Tags: java, json, apache-kafka, apache-flink, flink-streaming

i have a very strange issue with flink.
I have a json in input with some fields defined inside a pojo.
When i see the output, the = symbols are changed:

original string:

```
"body": "/opensearch/OpenSearch?searchTerms=productType:OL_2_WFR___%20OR%20OL_2_WRR___%20OR%20SL_2_WST___%20OR%20SR_2_WAT___&count=10"
```

String produced by flink:

```
"body": "/opensearch/OpenSearch?searchTerms\u003dproductType:OL_2_WFR___%20OR%20OL_2_WRR___%20OR%20SL_2_WST___%20OR%20SR_2_WAT___\u0026count\u003d10"
```

someone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

They aren't, not really.

[As per the JSON spec](https://www.json.org/json-en.html), if the byte `0x09` (ASCII tab character) appears inside a JSON string, or if the byte sequence `0x5C 0x74` (The characters `\t`) appears, or if the sequence `0x5C 0x75 0x30 0x30 0x30 0x39` appears (the characters `\u0009`), **they all mean the exact same thing**: There is one character there in that string, and it is the tab.

If you're having trouble with this, your JSON library is broken. Get a better one.

Most likely your JSON library is not broken and instead, either [A] you are comparing raw JSON, or attempting to retrieve info from raw JSON using e.g. regular expressions. Stop doing that, it'll be an endless parade of such 'weirdness', because you're not supposed to do this. There are all sorts of ways you can have different JSON strings that means the same thing, or [B] there is no problem here and you can just continue; you merely saw the difference and understandably assumed that there is a difference here, or that it'll cause problems down the line.

Assuming you don't do silly things like attempting to parse JSON with regular expressions or comparing raw JSON and assume that means anything relevant about the content of it, **this will not be a problem**.

Specifically, `\u003d` and `=` are **identical** as per the JSON spec. Whatever processed this JSON decided to replace one sequence with another sequence that means the same thing, which is an allowed operation.

Comment: i am using the dissect function in logstash to retrieve the json starting from a log file. So i'm using regular expression to obtain all the fields that i need from the log format

Comment: @Dario Not workable; instead take the log message, get it parsed as JSON, then apply operations on said JSON (and not on raw text) to extract what you need.